# Same location with different proxy urls nginx

Tags: nginx, docker, proxy, nexus

We am trying to get nexus via nginx reverse proxy working as a private registry for docker images. We are able to perform all the operations such as pull,search and tag but not able to push to nexus registry .

Below is the nginx configuration under location block.

```
    location ~ ^/(v1|v2)/
    {
            proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto "https";
            proxy_pass              http://box.company.net:5555;
            proxy_read_timeout      90;
    }
```

We are able to search and pull images.

But with push we face below error.

```
x.x.x.x - admin [23/Jun/2017:14:32:34 +0800] "POST /v2/fedora/apache/blobs/uploads/?from=fedora%2Fssh&mount=sha256%3Aacd6cf67daf4cd1fcff55ece5a906a45e1569b81271b80136a1f5fecfa4546ed HTTP/1.1" 404 717 "-" "docker/1.12.6 go/go1.7.4 kernel/3.10.0-514.10.2.el7.x86_64 os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/1.12.6 \x5C(linux\x5C))"
```

when we try with proxy _pass url as http://box.company.net:4444, we are able to push but cant pull the images .

Is it possible in nginx to pass two different proxy_pass urls under the same location but for different request methods . Any help would be really great ..Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@sempasha : Thanks for you help . It working for me just with a minor tweak .
Below is the location block added to get it working.

```
  location / {
      proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        if ($request_method !~* GET) {
                proxy_pass              http://box.company.net:4444;
        }
        if ($request_method = GET) {
                proxy_pass              http://box.company.net:5555;
        }
      proxy_read_timeout      90;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [if](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#if) or [map](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html) directives to select backend port.

Note, that [If is Evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/), not in you case of course.

```
location ~ ^/(v1|v2)/
{
    set $port 5555;
    if ($request_method = POST) {
        set $port 4444;
    }
    proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto "https";
    proxy_pass              http://box.company.net:$port;
    proxy_read_timeout      90;
}
```

Comment: This seems perfect...I will try your solution and get back with findings..Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks . It working for me but had to make some minor tweaks to get it to work